# ckeditor dynamically add uiElement

Tags: ckeditor, uielement

I want to dynamically add `UIElement`s to a dialog depending on the value of another uiElement..I believe what i need is defined here : http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.contentObject.html#add. unfortunately, there is no usage example..What object do i need to create to use this function? Ive tried dialog.add(), but this does not work? Can someone help me put here please? 
Thanks

Comment: by any chance did you manage to make it work ?? I am stuck exactly where you are and need to dynamically add text fields with onClick function of existing button in a dialog ... please let me know

Answer (score -3):

You can do it by using the addUIElement method.
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dialog.html#.addUIElement

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.addUIElement(typeName, builder)
```